# Start a new thread in Python with a callback method in Main Thread for PyQT application

Tags: python, multithreading, qt

**Situation :**

I'm C#/JS developper and I'm new to Python.
I'm developping a application using Python 2.7 and PyQT 4

In my main Window, I'm calling a method that is taking at least 15 seconds to execute.

This method is blocking my main thread and this is a problem for me because I want the user
to be able to move the window even if the program is running calculation.

So I thought about using thread but I want to be able to be notified when the thread has 
finished it's job to refresh the data on the window.

If I call a new function in the created thread, it will create a new thread and it 
is nos permitted to modify the QT GUI from a different thread than the Main one.

**Question  :**

***Is there a way to start a new Thread (not a process) that will run a method and call another method from 
the Main Thread once the process is over ?***

Clearly, I want to be able to have a equivalence to the JavaScript.jQuery.ajax() in a 
Python Environnement.

Comment: You'll probably get a lot of suggestions to use a separate process rather than a thread, due to Python's [Global Interpreter Lock](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/03/31/pythons-hardest-problem/). What does your function do, request data or perform calculations?

Comment: My function is a Network scanner that run the MSDOS command `net view` and return a list of computers (hostname and ip adresss (`socket.gethostbyname(hostname)`). I tried using a Pool, but the Pool I used created a new Process, and a new "Main Window"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `QThread` and signal and slots. `QThread` inherits from `QObject`, which allows to emit signals.

Upon the completion of the task, the QThread will emit a `finished()` signal

**Edit**

If you define a custom Thread like this:

```
class CustomThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, target, slotOnFinished=None):
        super(CustomThread, self).__init__()
        self.target = target
        if slotOnFinished:
            self.finished.connect(slotOnFinished)

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.target(*args, **kwargs)
```

You will be able to do:

```
class MyCustomWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyCustomWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        button = QtGui.QPushButton("Start", self)
        layout.addWidget(button)    
        button.clicked.connect(self.onStart)
        self.actionthread = CustomThread(target=self.longAction, self.onFinished)

    def onFinished(self):
        # Do Something

    def longAction(self):
        time.sleep(3)

    def onStart(self): 
        self.actionthread.start()
```

Comment: I'm going to test it tonight and mark you anwser as the good one if it worked. Is it possible to create a decorator for that "Custom Thread" to be able to pass it 2 parameter : The Method to call, the method to call back at the end of the treatment ?

Comment: I just edited my answer. Simpler to rewrite the CustomThread class than to use a decorator

Comment: I got an error with the line `CustomThread(target=self.longAction, self.onFinished)` so had to change it slightly to `CustomThread(self.longAction, self.onFinished)`